# Wrong helix handedness for badges

Tags: bug, design

Can we please fix the left-handed helices in the badge icons?

The site icon uses the “correct” right-handed helix (i.e. the one more commonly found in biology). Just mirroring the icons along the Y axis would do it.

Comment: So glad I wasn't the only one annoyed by this.  It's like when publicity people get a hold of "pretty" pseudo-colored images that are scientifically trash.  I'll never forget when an awful EM photo I took was turned into a banner.

Comment: It's clearly Z form.

Comment: Though the pitch is a little off…

Comment: Yes! I came to meta to say this - as usual Konrad you got there fist :)

Comment: Why hasn't this been fixed yet? Should be quick and easy.

Comment: @fileunderwater It seems like irrelevant minutia. Everybody can recognize it as a nucleic acid, which is all that matters for an icon. If you want it to be accurate, you would also have to change the base pair geometry. Also, left handed helices likely exist in nature.

Comment: http://users.fred.net/tds/leftdna/

Comment: this seems like it's fixed, right?